# Why this two movies appear in live action?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lego-batman-movie

*The Lego Batman Movie* showed the Nolan Batman Series and the Batman Collection (1989-1997) in Lego format, but they didn't show **Jerry Maguire** and **Batman: The Movie (1966)** in Lego format. Why?

Comment: Is there any reason it *would* include Jerry Maguire? I've never seen it but I'm not aware of it having any connection to the Batman mythos.

Comment: It does include a clip from *Jerry Maguire*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the Lego Batman was watching the actual *Jerry Maguire* movie...there's no reason to remake it in Lego format.

Equally, not all of the previous Batman movies were recreated in Lego format although some were...where it made sense.

The exceptions are:

**1997**

[image]

and **1966** (the weird one) as you mentioned

[image]

The problem with those two movies is that they would be very hard to recreate in Lego and **still be identifiable** as direct references to posters/screenshot from the original movies in the very short time they are on screen.

I wish anyone luck in trying to recreate that 1966 Batman scene in animated Lego.

So, it makes sense to use actual images / video.